# What is the word for when you do something of high quality, then don't like the original because it's worse?

Tags: single-word-requests

An example: Let's say you eat gas station sushi every Friday and love it. Then, you go to Japan and try the sushi of dreams! Finally, you try gas station sushi, but this time it's repulsive compared to what you had. You can't do anything but complain about the lack of flavor, the bad quality ingredients, the stomach issues, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could say that it **ruined** gas station sushi for you. [The Free Dictionary defines "ruin" in this sense as:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ruin)

> To harm or damage the enjoyment or experience of (something) greatly

Answer (score 0):

After visiting Japan, you **turned your nose up at** gas station sushi.

> to not accept something because you do not think it is good enough for you:
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/turn-nose-up

not a single word, but an apt idiom.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be 'discernment'? - Meaning you are now able to discern the difference in quality